# AWS S3 get keys containing text

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to fetch the files from S3.

As usual, my files are organised in the bucket as below:

```
bucket/<prefixes>/files
```

I want to retrieve files having specific file names

E.g.:

1. Files starting with a given text (myfile-*)
2. Files having specific extensions (*.csv)
3. File names having specific text (*text*)

For the first scenario, I can get away using prefix as below:

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName, "test/myfile");
```

But for the other 2 cases, I'm not able to find any solution.

I tried using wildcards as below:

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName, "test/*.csv");
```

But it didn't return any result.

Is there any workaround for this (other than getting the list of keys and filtering within my code)??

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Approximately how many files would be in this bucket? 100s, 1000s, millions?

Comment: It could be any number.. I don't have any control over ingestion. Files are ingested by 3rd parties

Comment: Did you find a solution for the 2° case?

Answer (score 2):

Your use-case is pretty common.

I am unaware of any S3 API that allows you to do anything other than prefix-matching.

The way to deal with this is to maintain a separate, searchable copy of the file names (and perhaps other metadata). In other words, have a row in a table in a relational database for each file. Or you might maintain an "index" file that lists all of the file names.

If the file creation/deletion is performed through your code, you can add the required code to keep the file list in sync with your bucket. If not, then you can use [S3 event notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations) to drive the file list updates.

When you want to search by file names, you look in the file list or database table to get the matching file names. Then hit S3 to do whatever operation is required.

Comment: I wouldn't have to be a relational database. It could be a NoSQL database, or even a search engine like Elasticsearch.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, and it could even be a flat file.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of AWS services like DynamoDB and Elasticsearch that can be updated automatically when a new file arrives in S3.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it, there is no wildcards in S3, and a file can even contain the * character

Comment: So.. I can only retrieve the file names starting with a text, but not ending or containing a give text...

Comment: Seems so :( you can only get files from S3 by prefix. or by encoding.
If you need more, you can fetch all files, and use regex